# rename directories recursively window command line For

Tags: window, command

I need to copy a directory tree and at the same time rename directories with a given name to another name anywhere such name is found in the path:

replace "d" to "k" any where it is found under c:\a\b\c and its sub directories. So,

```html
from: c:\a\b\c\d
to:   c:\a\b\c\k
and
from: c:\a\b\c\d\e\d\f\d\...
to:   c:\a\b\c\k\e\k\f\k\...
```

```
for /r "C:\a\b\c\" %%x in (*d*) do ren "%%x" *k*
```

The command prompt window opens and closes very fast and no output in the directory c:\a\b\c is noted.  Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: And by 'not doing it', you mean: a) not doing anything at all, b) throwing an error (which?) c) doing the dishes instead d/k) doing somebody else instead (check all that apply)

Comment: I just edited the question to provide more explanation to what happens when command is run.